# How to create an individual results page using Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build a small multipage web application using flask. So far my app consists of two separate routes. The first route renders a small webform that triggers an api request, which generates data that are unique to each user and session. The data come with a unique id for each api response. The second route is used to display the unique results for each user. How can I create an individual results page for each user that is threadsafe und ensures that the data is not accessible to any other user?

Pseudo code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect 

app = Flask(__name__)

# A simple webform 
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_form(): 
 
  if request.method == "POST":
    
    # Validate form and perform api request
    
    return redirect(url_for('view_results'))

  return render_template('main.html')

# Results page
@app.route('/results', methods=['GET'])
def view_results():

  # Show an individual results page
  
  return render_template('results.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is much wide. Here is tones of ways how to realise it.

Closer example will be looks like:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_form(): 
 
  if request.method == "POST":

    # get user id to be able redirect to specific results page
    user_id = request.form.get('user_id')
    
    # redirect to page for exact user_id
    return redirect(url_for('view_results/' + user_id))

  return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/results/<user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def view_results(user_id=None):

  # Show an individual results according user_id
  if user_id == 'blahblah':
    return render_template('results_for_blahblah.html')
  
  # if user_id is None return a standard dummy results
  return render_template('results.html')
```

1. Get `user_id` from request form data
2. Redirect to new URL with `user_id` query parameter
3. Respond specifically generated template for specific user with `user_id`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I replaced `url_for('view_results/' + user_id)` with `url_for('view_results', user_id = user_id)` and it works fine.

Comment: The code above trusts the user input. So a user logged in with user_id=1 might fabricate a request with user_id=2 as the input and steal the info of the user with user_id=2.

Comment: @branco I just answered to exact question. This is not Flask manual. Login, session and security aspects are out of scope. But, yes this example is insecure and shouldn't be held private and sensitive data.

Comment: @branco thank you for your response. In my example the users are actually already logged in. The id I am using comes from the api itself and not from user input. It is only used to seperate the unique queries, which do not contain sensitive or personal information but information that should nonetheless be kept seperate for each user.

Answer (score 0):

To have some security in your application's handling of users and their session you should look into the flask plugin Flask-Login.

I recommend that you also check The Flask Mega-Tutorial by Miguel Grinberg and the guides from OWASP.

Also as a matter of principle never ever trust user input as rzlvmp's response does. It may be fabricated to steal someone else's private data from your site.